# How to filter picklist values based on condition in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, administration

I am using a screen flow where I used picklist. I need to display the picklist values based on condition. If I used Component visibility , the whole picklist component is hided instead only the values should display based on condition.  How can I achieve this? Thanks in Advance!
[image: Work type group stage][image: picklist]

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a LWC component for this and get values for Combobox
> from apex based on your condition requirement and then use that
> component in your flow.

It would be great if you can provide more details on this such as one example based on condition.

> One more thing I can think of is that you can create metadata based on
> your condition and picklist values. Then you can query metadata
> records filtered by the condition and use those as picklist values.

**Edit -**

You can perform the following steps -

> 1. Create one Custom Metadata and on a custom field in that Metadata (ex. - Category)
> 2. Now add records in that metadata with the label as your picklist value and category as Work Type Group value which are shown in screen
>    1 of your flow.
> 3. Create a new resource in your flow of type Record Choice Set and use the custom metadata records which are created in the above steps
>    filtered by category field.
> 4. Use the Resouce created in above step 3 as choices in your flow.

If you follow these steps you will achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Suthar, I have added 2 images, The first image is the work type group stage. If I select Meet with Health Advocate, Picklist values should be west coast and east coast. If I select Stemwell Doctor, Picklist values should be Colombia and Canada

Comment: Hi @SanjanaRajasekar, I have edited my answer based on the updates in question. You just need to follow the steps carefully. I hope it will help.